# How do you reset only a specific table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake, reset

I have the tables (Maybe they're not called that) Users and Posts. I added a lot of tests posts to the Posts table (maybe it's called a database) so I want to wipe it. I know that I could use **rake db:reset** but that would also wipe the Users table.

Does anyone know how to reset only a specific table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be better off creating a rake task for this.  You could even namespace it inside of 'db' if you wanted.  ie `rake db:reset_unimportant_models`

In that task u can then do something like: `ModelName.delete_all`

For more info on delete_all check here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all

For more info on creating rake tasks, check here: http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial

Here is an example of what you might do:

```
# lib/tasks/reset_unimportant_models_task.rake
namespace :db do
  desc "Sequentially clears out the models I don't care about"
  task :reset_unimportant_models => :environment do
    puts "Clearing out the BlahModel model"
    BlahModel.destroy_all
    puts "Finished."
  end
end
```

You would then call that like:
`rake db:reset_unimportant_models`
and when you run `rake -T` u will see it up with the db:blah tasks

Comment: Where `delete_all` might create referential integrity errors (for example a post's comments might be orphaned), use `destroy_all` to trigger the relevant callbacks.

Comment: However, that doesn't actually reset the table. IDs would follow sequentially from the lastly created record, right?

Answer (score 5):

While I agree creating a rake task is the better solution, sometimes you just want to get in there and quickly clear something out.

If you run `rails console`, you can then do a call to `ModelName.delete_all` from there.

Consider this a poor alternate solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use an IRB console:

```
irb(main):001:0> Post.delete_all
```

Comment: Just remember to launch the console with the correct environment (defaults to development) using the RAILS_ENV=environment argument. So if you want to manipulate production DB items, launch IRB with "irb RAILS_ENV=production" or "script/console production".